# How to properly access a belongs_to model's properties

Tags: ruby, datamapper, model-associations, ruby-datamapper

Using the following classes and their associations.

```
class Repository
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  has n, :branches
end

class Branch
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :note, String
  belongs_to :repository
end

# Simple creation of a repository and branch belonging to said repository
repo = Repository.new
repo.name = "Bob"
branch = repo.branches.new
branch.note = "Example Note"
repo.save

# Print the repo->branch's note
puts repo.branches.first.note  # Prints "Example Note"

# Print the branch->repo name
puts branch.repository.first.name  # Does not work
puts branch.repository.name  # Does not work
```

I can access properties down from *Repository* (ex: `Repository.first.branches.first.note`).

I cannot seem to access properties up from *Branch*, getting the repository's name from a branch (ex: `Branch.first.repository.first.name`).

---

** SOLVED **
Turns out that I cannot actual use **Repository** as my class name as DataMapper already uses it [(API)](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.1.0/DataMapper/Repository). Solution is to simply rename my class and then it all works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the class name **Repository** as DataMapper already uses it [(API)](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.1.0/DataMapper/Repository). Solution is to simply rename the class and then it all works as intended.